# Storing a number exactly as written without setting it to text mode

Tags: microsoft-excel

I maintain a bunch of spreadsheets where I have to enter values from reports I am given. I need to enter the values in the spreadsheet with the same number of decimals as in the report. Excel will however remove trailing zeroes or round. If I type in 0,00400 I want it displayed exactly like that.
Searched for similar questions but all the solutions seem to revolve around storing as text, setting fixed numbers of decimals for columns or they are solutions to removing trailing zeroes which I don't want to.

I can't set a fixed number of decimal places for each column, because they are not the same every time. I just want the numbers to be stored exactly as I enter them. I've played around with custom formats but can't seem to find any that both prevents rounding but also retains trailing zeroes.

Storing as text seems to be the main suggestion I've found, but it is not an option, because the numbers are used in formulas in several other spreadsheets. Finding which ones and changing them is more effort than I'm willing to put in, particularly as I'm not the author of them.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: You don't need to set a format for the entire column, it's also possible to adjust the format for a single cell only.

Comment: This can be achieved either using a macro to look at the text and convert it to the appropriate number or with a user defined function. I will put one together on the weekend if no one else gets to it.

Answer (score 2):

> Searched for similar questions but all the solutions seem to revolve around storing as text

Actually there is no really another option, Excel doesn't have any concept of "relevant digits", so it can't save the numbers just as you've typed.

A workaround could be to have two columns: one to store text, and use another column for the value (you can calculate it with [`VALUE` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/value-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2)).

If that still doesn't work for you, then Excel is not the tool for this task.